# Get WooCommerce Order ID from Plugin

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to create a payment gateway and I need to get the WooCommerce order ID. Problem is the notice I'm getting and to be fair, I am new to the world of WordPress and WooCommerce.

**Notice**: `Notice: ID was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly.`

This is my code:

```
public function get_order_details( $post ) {
if ( $post->post_type=="shop_order" ) : 
$order = new WC_Order( $post );
if ( $order ) :
```

I'm later, whenever needed, referencing it like this: `<?php echo $order->get_id; ?>`

I'm using the latest WP and WC versions. If anyone can point me in the right direction in terms of how to get the Order ID from my plugin, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Replace `$order->get_id` with `$order->get_id()`

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick.